# JQuery doesn't reload even if data is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, authentication

I've got this function which checks if the login data is correct (username and password) with ajax.
If the php result is an error, then I print the error, but if the result is empty I would like to reload the page.

```
function(data) {
  if (data.length && data != null) {
    $("span.error").remove();
    $(".login-overlay .login h3").after('<span class="error">' + data + '</span>');
  } else {
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

The issue is that when the php result (data) is empty, the code prints an empty span

```
<span class="error"></span>
```

I think the error is in the **if clause**, but I tried everything:

```
data.length
data.length > 0
data != undefined
data != null
data
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I think you have to check  data != null first and then data.length > 0

Comment: This is straightforward to debug; what do you get if you `console.log(data)` or `console.log(data.length)`?

Comment: please share how `data` will look like if there is an error and if it is successful

Comment: also you should use `location.reload(true);` to get back at the server instead of reloading fetcjed page from start

Comment: Could you paste your php code too?

Comment: you have error in your if check if value will be null it will throw exception. You need to swap your checks and instead if `!= null` maybe better `if (data && data.length)`

Comment: Why remove `span.error` and add it again? Assuming `span.error` is already on the page, you can just use `$("span.error").html(data)`. Or use `$("span.error").text(data)` if there's no HTML.

Comment: I tried to put an alert("'"+data+"'") to understand what the data is when there is no error. Well, inside the quotes I put in the alert, it shows this 
' //quote put by me
' //quote put by me

So two quotes for each line with an empty space between them (?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function(data) {
  if (data && data.trim()) {
    data = data.trim();
    $("span.error").remove();
    $(".login-overlay .login h3").after('<span class="error">' + data + '</span>');
  } else {
    location.reload();
  }
}
```

You probably just want to check whether data is defined. So this should work. Otherwise please show what the `data` exactly. Which you could do by doing `console.log(data)` at the start of your function

Comment: I've already tried that, but it doesn't work. I also tried this: in the php file, if there's no error, I print a "success". Now, in the .js file I tried this: if(data == "success"), but still doesn't work. So, I tried logging the data with console.log(data); and the data comprends "success" and an empty space on the following line.

Comment: Seems like there is some extra whitespacing happening. Ideally you want to resolve that in your endpoint. For now you could try using `.trim()` on your data first. I'll update the answer

Comment: Could you show display the result of `console.log(data)` when it is empty?

Comment: Good to hear, if you have access to the php I would recommend doing the actually trim on that side

Answer (score 0):

I think that since your checking for both the data and the data.length the IF statement is not passed. your passing data from the server wither way, so probably there will always be data and the IF statement won't work. I would try the following code if indeed DATA is a string:

```
function(data) {
    if(data.length > 0){
    $("span.error").remove();
    $(".login-overlay .login h3").after('<span class="error">'+data+'</span>');
} else {
    location.reload(); }
}
```